# What are the differerences between the new Ada sub-pool features and pools of pools?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, ada

I recently read [the 2012 rationale](http://www.adacore.com/uploads/technical-papers/Ada2012_Rationale_Chp5_iterators_pools_etc.pdf) portion on iterators and pools. One of the things overviewed is the new abilities concerning subpools, one question that was unanswered is what's the difference between subpools and pools of pools - I mean it seems the same [as pg.25] could rather be achieved like this:

```ada
-- Minnesota: Land of 10,000 Lakes
type Minnesota(Size: Storage_Count) is new Root_Storage_Pool with private;
type Lake(Size: Storage_Count) is new Root_Storage_Pool with private
     with Storage_Pool => Minnasota;
-- ...
type Pooled is [...] with Storage_Pool => Lake;
```

Though I admit I might be horribly wrong, as I haven't used sub-pools, much less pools (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Randy Brukardt of [Comp.Lang.Ada](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.ada/OmM3Ior4CwI).

> Aspect Storage_Pool only applies to access types ([13.11(15)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-11.html) and
>   others), and type Lake is not an access type, so this is illegal (and
>   makes no sense as well).
>
> You could implement one pool by putting other pools within its
>   implementation (say Minnesota here including a an array of 10000 Lakes
>   :-). But you'd then have to have a way to select which item belongs to
>   each, ahem, subpool. And you'd be reinventing the wheel.
>
> There is also the issue of finalization. The subpool mechanism ensures
>   that objects don't outlive their subpool (pointers to the objects
>   might outlive the subpool, but not the object themselves), even when
>   the subpool is explicitly destroyed early (just as
>   Unchecked_Deallocation does). There's no good way to do that without
>   language support (every hand-written subpool implementation that we
>   talked about insisted that no controlled, protected, or task objects
>   be allocated from it, which is obviously limiting).
>
> Let me assure you, getting this right was hard and contentious. It was
>   nearly dropped a couple of times. Doing it yourself wouldn't be
>   contentious (I hope!), but it would still be hard. Since the ARG has
>   already done the dirty work, it's best to use it.
>
> ```
>                                             Randy.
> ```